# CSS - How can I vertically align a div without using "position: absolute"?

Tags: html, css

How can I vertically align a div without using `position: absolute`?

I created the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h5c21hmj/14/

```css
#main {
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;        
}

.image {
    background-image: url(http://www.todopuertas.net/images/conoce.png);
    height: 100px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.column1 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.column2 {
    float: right;
    right: 0;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="column1">
        <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sit amet egestas urna. Sed dignissim bibendum ante, sit amet accumsan erat ornare quis. Proin in neque diam. Phasellus rhoncus hendrerit leo, sit amet feugiat ante pellentesque vitae.
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to get the div that contains the image and align it to the bottom, but I need to achieve that without using "absolute" positioning, only using "relative" positioning on all elements.

I can't use "absolute" because it gets above other elements.

Comment: Above which elements? Could you also add them to your example?

Comment: I really don't know why down voting  your question, you include the desired behavior, a specific problem, the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself and a jsfiddle so you have my +1.

Comment: thx. I decided to use the `inline-block` because I was a bit concerned, please don't take it personal, it's just that I feel more comfortable witht he other method. I have a lot of code here, so if I reverse it now, it will take me hours to get a good result....
can we work on the `inline-block` method?

Comment: Nevermind, looks like flex is going better. Still testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox like this:

Here a working [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/7L7nz07s/) fork from yours

```css
#main {
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex; /*added*/
}

.image {
    background-image: url(http://www.todopuertas.net/images/conoce.png);
    height: 100px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 100%;  /*added to bottom align the img*/
}

.column1 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    align-self: flex-end; /*added to aligned to bottom*/
    border: 1px solid; /*to show that is aligned*/
}

.column2 {
    float: right;
    right: 0;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="column1">
        <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sit amet egestas urna. Sed dignissim bibendum ante, sit amet accumsan erat ornare quis. Proin in neque diam. Phasellus rhoncus hendrerit leo, sit amet feugiat ante pellentesque vitae.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's good to see flex box answers, but you should always warn the OP about browser [in]compatibility..

Comment: @JoaquínO all new browsers support flexbox, but you are right so here is the list of browsers: **http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox**

Comment: Thx for the both of you. Now the major problem here is that the div is aligned to the bottom, but the image isn't.

Comment: @user3692451 That is because the `div.image` has `height: 100px` and `background-size: contain` so the img don't fit the height of the `div.image`  if you want to maintain that height for some reason add `background-position-y: 100%;` to `.image`, if not just adjust the height of `div.image`

Comment: @user3692451 I edited the snippet of my answer to bottom align the img, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking out of your time to do this, but what about the compatibility part that Joaquín O talked about?

Comment: @user3692451 Check out the [**list**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) that I post and you will see that most browsers support it, and my opinion is that flexbox is the present and future and it's not just my opinion, check this out https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/ it dates back 2 years ago, an this http://www.sitepoint.com/are-we-ready-to-use-flexbox/ a year ago.

Comment: Someone downvoted my question, can you point me what I should fix in the question in order to prevent future downvotes?

Comment: I marked your answer as the best one. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5c21hmj/16/). Basically, i removed the floats and set your elements to align bottom, by setting them as `inline-block` elements.

Comment: I'm giving it a try. Never thought `inline-block` was for this kind of situation. You have opened my eyes.